# How many times are the words "Harry" and/or "Harry Potter" spoken in the Harry Potter movies?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, names

How many times do people actually say Harry's name in all 8 movies?

I'll accept either

> "**Harry**"

or

> "**Harry Potter**"

since just "Potter" could count for Lily and James as well.

Comment: Arranging a HP marathon with friends and drink every time someone says ‘Harry’... I will give you the answer after 3 days of hangover.

Comment: In the book series his name is mentioned *loads* (27 time in book 1, 87 time in book 2, 13 times in book 3, 80 times in book 4, 37 times in book 5, 34 times in book 6 and 44 times in book 7).

Comment: Do Harry's many Hogwarts admission letters count?

Comment: This just begs for "too many".

Comment: How is this too broad?

Comment: I agree this is not too broad. There is one correct answer.

Comment: Modified the title to better reflect the question and hopefully help alleviate the wrong-headed "too broad" votes

Comment: The edits to clarify the question are fine. I don't approve of altering the text to represent the OP differently.

Comment: @LeoKing - Ah, sorry. I mistook atayenel's comment for one from you.

Comment: Haha, that's a new one for me on SE. No harm done.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Assuming the subtitles haven't missed any instances, **Harry Potter's full name occurs 134 times in total**.

- **17 times** in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
- **26 times** in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
- **6 times** in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
- **12 times** in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
- **6 times** in Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix
- **21 times** in Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince
- **19 times** in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part I
- **27 times** in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Part II

and

- **The word "Harry" appears a grand total of 695 times.**
- **The word "Potter" appears a grand total of 265 times.**

---

Purely for the record, his name occurs in the *books* quite a lot too;

- **27 times** in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
- **87 time** in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
- **13 times** in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
- **80 times** in Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
- **37 times** in Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix
- **34 times** in Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince
- **44 times** in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows.

---

Also for the record, if your plan is to drink a shot of tequila each time his name is said, you'll be over the [UK drink-driving limit](https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/alcohol-facts/alcohol-and-the-law/drink-driving-and-the-legal-alcohol-limit/) within the first 30 minutes of the start of the first film and **[dead](https://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/alcoholoverdosefactsheet/overdoseFact.pdf)** by the end of the second one.

Comment: Interesting that Harry appears more than Potter. I would not have guessed that.

Comment: @Skooba - All of his friends call him Harry.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer! This was just what I was looking for.

Comment: I think perhaps in your ‘for the record’ bit you ought to clarify that you’re limiting book occurrences to the _full_ name; otherwise the numbers for the books are of course far too low. In _Prisoner of Azkaban_, for example, the name Harry appears 2,122 times, excluding Hagrid’s _’Arry_. (Puzzlingly, I count 15 instances of “Harry Potter” in the book, not 13; or 11 if you only count characters speaking the name.)

Answer (score 20):

Every *Harry Potter* Movie but only the words "Harry" and "Potter":

This might help. I would however advise viewer discretion, can lead to feeling of intense peevedness if viewed continuously.

Comment: If you let it run long enough it becomes sort of meditative.

Comment: "Harry" no longer sounds like a name...

Comment: @DqwertyC: Nor does "Potter".

Comment: Is this Flater related to our Flater?

Comment: I started to hear 'Henry' by the end. Raises the question, who (aside Harry) has their name said the most?

Comment: This looks like a link-only answer, except it's a video-only answer in which if the video is blocked/removed, then the answer is useless. Consider [edit] and improve the answer by really mentioning how many.

Comment: Or better yet transcribe the video in the answer

Comment: @user13267 - the transcript: "Harry Potter, Harry, Harry Potter, Potter, Harry, Harry, Potter......" :D